# Code executes derived class method, but gets default parameter from base class method

Tags: c++, virtual, derived, default-parameters

Can someone explain why the result of the code below would be "class B::1" ?

**Why does the virtual method of derived class uses the default parameter of a base class and not his own?** For me this is pretty strange. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void func(int a = 1)
    {
        cout << "class A::" << a;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void func(int a = 2)
    {
        cout << "class B::" << a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A * a = new B;
    a->func();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because default arguments are resolved according to the static type of `this` (ie, the type of the variable itself, like `A&` in `A& a;`).

Modifying your example slightly:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void func(int a = 1)
    {
        std::cout << "class A::" << a << "\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void func(int a = 2)
    {
        std::cout << "class B::" << a << "\n";
    }
};

void func(A& a) { a.func(); }

int main()
{
    B b;
    func(b);
    b.func();

    return 0;
}
```

We observe the following output:

```
class B::1
class B::2
```

In action at [ideone](http://ideone.com/xddDI).

It is not recommended that a virtual function change the default value for this reason. Unfortunately I don't know any compiler that warns on this construct.

---

The technical explication is that there are two ways of dealing with default argument:

- create a new function to act as trampoline: `void A::func() { func(1); }`
- add-in the missing argument at the call site `a.func()` => `a.func(/*magic*/1)`

If it were the former (and assuming that the `A::func` was declared `virtual` as well), then it would work like you expect. However the latter form was elected, either because issues with `virtual` were not foreseen at the time or because they were deemed inconsequential in face of the benefits (if any...).

Answer (score 5):

Because default value is substituted during compilation and is taken from declaration, while real function to be called (A::func or B::func) is determined at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Because polymorphism in C++ takes effect at run-time, whereas the substitution of default parameters takes effect at compile-time.  At compile time, the compiler does not know (and is not supposed to know) the dynamic type of the object to which the pointer `a` points.  Hence, it takes the default argument for the only type it knows for `a`, which in your example is `A *`.

(This incidentally is also the reason default parameters are given in interfaces/headers rather than in implementations/definitions.  The compiler never inserts the default parameter in the implementation's machine code, but only in the *caller's* machine code.  Technically, the default parameter is the property of the caller; and the caller doesn't know -- and shouldn't need to know -- an object's dynamic type.)